# React.renderComponent is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs, react-dom

I have read some articles for beginners about ReactJs. The article I read showed only code fragments. I'm having trouble with my first component:

full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HELLO WORLD</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>


<script type="text/babel">
    var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            return React.DOM.h1("hello world!!");
        }
    });

    React.renderComponent(
        HelloWorld,
        document.getElementById("content")
    );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the page I see `embedded:11 Uncaught TypeError: React.renderComponent is not a function`

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

I've also tried this with no luck:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.js"></script>
<!--    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser.js"></script>-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HELLO WORLD</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>


<script type="text/babel">
    var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello world!!");
        }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(HelloWorld, null), document.getElementById("content"));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: I see that you use `babel-core` `browser.js`, which has been deprecated, remove it and use React directly.

Remove `script` type and replace everything with:

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello world!!");
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(HelloWorld, null), document.getElementById("content"));
```

[jsbin demo](https://jsbin.com/deluveyuxi/edit)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your first example is that `React.renderComponent` is not a function, you need to use `ReactDOM.render` instead. You should save yourself a lot of effort now and just use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) and use this application. It takes all of the pain out of the tooling that you will need to make React fast to use (webpack hot module reloading). It is extremely simple compared to the average tooling you will need to setup taking any other route and is made by the people that make React.  I can tell by the version number of React that you are using, the tutorial you are going of of is *very* old, a very longtime before Facebook released create-react-app when things were more difficult.

If you are going to go about it inline, use this in your head -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.min.js" integrity="sha256-cLWs9L+cjZg8CjGHMpJqUgKKouPlmoMP/0wIdPtaPGs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.js" integrity="sha256-M5lc1yUhpXlm2VZjGk4aoFwqR9H1OJ0p5MR5xpipulk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Full working example on React 15** -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.min.js" integrity="sha256-cLWs9L+cjZg8CjGHMpJqUgKKouPlmoMP/0wIdPtaPGs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.js" integrity="sha256-M5lc1yUhpXlm2VZjGk4aoFwqR9H1OJ0p5MR5xpipulk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>HELLO WORLD</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <script>
    var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello world!!");
        }
    });
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(HelloWorld, null), document.getElementById("content"));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```